# Background color for link not working

Tags: html, css

The background color for the active link class is not showing. The border is changed to dashed, but the color isn't changing. What is going on? I am new to css and a little frustrated. Please help! Oh, the color isn't working either. I just did that to test it. I don't really want white text on a white background.

```css
nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 75%;

}

nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

a:link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(86, 19, 139, 1);
}

a:visited{
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 1);
}

.active{
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
  <nav>
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
   <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
   <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit further what you expect to happen.

Comment: do you want to change font color?

Answer (score 1):

As @OvidiuUnguru pointed out, the `background` and `color` properties are not affected because of **CSS selector priority**, or to use the right term, [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). It states that the most precise/specific case will be the last applied and `a:link` is more precise than `.active`.

You could use `!important`, but the priority rules will still apply, unless there is only one `!important` rule... This is, IMO to be avoided since it can cause side effects later on. MDN covers the best practices of !important:

> Some rules of thumb:
>
> Always look for a way to use specificity before even considering
>   !important
>
> Only use !important on page-specific CSS that overrides
>   foreign CSS (from external libraries, like Bootstrap or
>
> Never use !important when you're writing a
>   plugin/mashup.
>
> Never use !important on site-wide CSS.

Also, I'm pretty sure you do not expect to have EVERYTHING that is `.active` be like those links, you might apply different styling either for the active section of the page, the active button, and so on. So your best bet, is to be more precise. In the code snippet here, I simply added `a` in front of your selector to make it the most precise `a.active`.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 75%;
}

nav a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

a:link {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  color: rgba(86, 19, 139, 1);
}

a:visited {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 1);
}

a.active {
  background-color: white !important;
  color: white !important;
  border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
    <a href="history.html" class="active">History</a>
    <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the background isn't white on the "active" class, it's because priority. `a:visited` and `a:link` have higher priority than your `.active` class.

You can do it like this

```css
nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 75%;

}

nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

a:link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(86, 19, 139, 1);
}

a:visited{
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 1);
}

.active{
    background-color: white !important;
    color: white !important;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
 <header>
  <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
  <nav>
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
   <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
   <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Though, I don't see the reason why would would use `:link` and `:visited` in the first place.

Comment: :visited is very useful, can't believe you don't see a reason for using it... While :link is more rare, there are still very valid uses!

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 75%;

}

nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

a:link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(86, 19, 139, 1);
}

a:visited{
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 1);
}

.active{
    background-color: white !important;
    color: white;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
  <nav>
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
   <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
   <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
  </nav>
 </header>
```

Comment: You could maybe add an explanation to the code in order to help just a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will help you

if you want change "font color" then use

```
.active {
    color: white !important;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

if you want change "background color" then use

```
.active {
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

if you want change both "font and background color" then use

```
.active {
    color: red !important;
    background-color: white !important;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same results as others have provided without using `!important`

```css
nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 75%;

}

nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

a:link {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(86, 19, 139, 1);
}

a:visited{
    background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
    color: rgba(171, 171, 171, 1);
}

/* new colors working!! */
a.active, a.active:link, a.active:visited {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
        <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
        <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

or you could simply do `a:link:not(.active)` and `a:visited:not(.active)` for the first two blocks